# How to use private framework's .h file in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

I am trying to use **SBSRemoteNotificationClient.h** file of SpringBoardServices framework downloaded from GitHub. I directly drag and dropped downloaded SBSRemoteNotificationClient.h file into Xcode and tried to compile it. But I am facing below error during compiling.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_SBSRemoteNotificationClient", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in MyClass.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I added #import "SBSRemoteNotificationClient.h" to my MyClass.m file.I also added path of SBSRemoteNotificationClient.h in Build Settings -> Search paths -> User Header Search paths like this **/Users/awsuser006/Desktop/iphone-private-frameworks-master/SpringBoardServices/**

But I am facing above mentioned error. Is this the right way of using .h files of private frameworks?

Answer (score 0):

This is a linker error. The header was correctly parsed, but the framework symbols were not found. Make sure you are linking the SpringBoardServices framework.

Use

```
find  /Applications/Xcode.app/ -name 'SpringBoardServices.framework'
```

to find it, then add `-framework SpringBoardServices` and `-F /the/path/returned/by/find/` (without `SpringBoardServices.framework` at the end of the path) to your compilation flags.

Adding the framework using `Build Phases > Link Binary With Libraries > (+)` in your Xcode project may also work.

Comment: Thank u for your reply. Adding the framework using Build Phases will not list private frameworks

Comment: Yes, obviously. But you can click "Add other..." and browse your drive to add any framework.

Comment: I tried it.But it is going to add SpringBoardServices folder with .h files downloaded from GitHub, but not SpringBoardServices.framework

Comment: ?? Click "Add other...", press Command+Shift+G, enter the path to the framework (eg `/Applications/Xcode.app//Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/` on my machine), then choose `SpringBoardServices.framework`. I just did it, it worked like a charm.

Comment: Note however that you'll probably need to edit the path to replace absolute reference to the platform frameworks directory with a Xcode build variable in order to support both iOS and the Simulator (eg. transform `/Applications/Xcode.app//Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Develop‌​er/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/` to `$SOME_XCODE_ENV_VARIABLE/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/`).

Comment: What is the value of $SOME_XCODE_ENV_VARIABLE. I didn't get this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62810/discussion-between-guillaume-algis-and-user2533604).

Answer (score -1):

1. Find the framework symbols
2. Drag & drop them into *Link with binaries...*